# ps_files_cleanup_dir: opendir(/var/lib/php/sessions) failed: Permission denied

Tags: php

> Notice: SessionHandler::gc(): ps_files_cleanup_dir:
>   opendir(/var/lib/php/sessions) failed: Permission denied (13)

I edit my php.ini file and add session.gc_probability = 0, but it not worked for me!

```
anboo@anboo-desktop:~/$ php -r "var_dump(ini_get('session.gc_probability'));"

string(1) "0"
```

CLI and FPM configurations is identical files

> $ php -v PHP 7.0.14-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) ( NTS ) Copyright
>   (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c)
>   1998-2016 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.14-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies

Comment: Please tell me what `0/100` equals? Or come to that what `0/anything` equals. That is what you have set the probability of the garbage collector being called to!!!!

Comment: Do you have the privilage to create/delete files in that directory? Does the account your web server runs under have the privlage to create/delete files in that directory?

Comment: Is turning of the session garbage collector really a good idea?